# QML: C++ model code segfaults when calling from ListView

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm getting segmentation fault when calling from QML a C++ method. The cause of the segfault is the function `endResetModel()`, however it occurs after exiting this function, as you can see on stack trace.

stack trace:

```
==12651== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==12651==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x8
==12651==    at 0x601BB4E: QtQml::qmlExecuteDeferred(QObject*) (in /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5.7.0)
==12651==    by 0x5146708: QQuickTransition::prepare(QList<QQuickStateAction>&, QList<QQmlProperty>&, QQuickTransitionManager*, QObject*) (in /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5.7.0)
==12651==    by 0x513D443: QQuickTransitionManager::transition(QList<QQuickStateAction> const&, QQuickTransition*, QObject*) (in /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5.7.0)
==12651==    by 0x69D077C: QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) (in /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.7.0)
==12651==    by 0x69D077C: QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) (in /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.7.0)
==12651==    by 0x8064FB7: QQuickAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) (in /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5.7.0)
==12651==    by 0x51DA707: QQuickItem::event(QEvent*) (in /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5.7.0)
==12651==    by 0x69A8989: QCoreApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) (in /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.7.0)
==12651==    by 0x69A8ADF: QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) (in /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.7.0)
==12651==    by 0x51EC089: QQuickWindow::sendEvent(QQuickItem*, QEvent*) (in /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5.7.0)
==12651==    by 0x51EC811: QQuickWindowPrivate::deliverMouseEvent(QMouseEvent*) (in /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5.7.0)
==12651==    by 0x51EF1F4: QQuickWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) (in /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5.7.0)
==12651==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==12651==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==12651==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==12651==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==12651==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

My C++ function does nothing really, just trying to catch this bug:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void qml_del_account(int index);
void Identities::qml_del_account(int index) {

    beginResetModel();
    endResetModel();

}
```

The weird thing is, segmentation fault only happens when I call `qml_del_account()` from a child of `ListView` object. As you can see on the QML, I can call this function from 2 places, from the button and from the menu.

QML:

```
Identities {
    id: identities
}
Pane {
    anchors {
        fill: parent
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: list_area
        border.color: "black"
        border.width: 2
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
            top: parent.top
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        Column {
            ListView {
                id: list_identities
                width: list_area.width
                height: 100
                model: identities
                delegate: Rectangle {
                        height: 40
                        width: parent.width
                        Text {
                            id: identities_item
                            height: parent.height
                            anchors.left: parent.left
                            width: 100
                            text: email                               
                        }
                        ToolButton {
                            anchors.right: parent.right
                            contentItem: Image {
                                    source: "qrc:/images/dots-menu.png"
                                    id: toolbtn_img
                                    width: 24
                                    height: 24
                            }
                            onClicked: optionsMenu.open()
                            Menu {
                                id: optionsMenu
                                MenuItem {
                                    text: "Delete"
                                    onTriggered: {                                        
                                        identities.qml_del_account(index) // <-- this call DOES produce a SEGFAULT
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            Button {
                text: "del"
                onClicked: {
                    identities.qml_del_account(0) // <-- this call DOES NOT produce a SEGFAULT
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

So, as I was saying, there are 2 use cases but only 1 produces SEGFAULT:

1. if I click on the button **"del"** there is NO SEGMENTATION FAULT
2. if I click on the popup menu option **"Delete"** I DO get SEGFAULT.

So my question is: Can I reset my model by a C++ code when the calling object is a child of the model view? (*list_identities* object in my example).

Or, probably I have some bug in the other code that messes up my object tree, hopefully not, valgrind shows nothing about such possibility.

Comment: Have you tried a different component to trigger the C++ function call? E.g. a `MouseArea`?
Maybe `Menu` or `MenuItem` don't like being deleted while they are currently being used.

Comment: @KevinKrammer, yes, I tried. With Image + MouseArea it works perfectly. Sooo... the big question is, is it a bug or what the heck is happening. If beginResetModel() and endResetModel recreates MenuItems then this is probably the cause. I think I will have to make a snippet and submit to QT team

Comment: My guess is that `Menu`, being a rather complex `Item`, cannot easily be deleted while it is basically the component the user currently interacts with.
What you can do, however, is to call the method that effects the reset in a delayed fashion. I.e. the method you call from QML will just call another methods through a single shot timer or `QMetaMethod::invokeMethod` with `Qt::QueuedConnection`.
This way the menu should have finished its operation by the time the reset happens